# SAML IssueInstant has . in stead of : when browser is Norwegian

Tags: windows-server-2016

My SAML request have IssueInstant="2019-04-08T14.04.45Z" when I use a browser with Norwegian language (locale:nb), but has the correct : when I change to English languange (locale:en). Anyone know where I can change this? This is on windos server 2016. We did not have the same issue in windows server 2012.

Comment: What webapp generates the SAML requests?

Comment: Yes, but I don't really know how it works. I add my SAML info in a web.config file on the back en server, but I think the web app generates the request. There is no place I can enter locale or time-format i my files, but it could be that the new windows server insist on using . in for Norwegian time format

Comment: Yes = Genus apps (https://docs.genus.no/)

Answer (score 0):

The people who run the servers found a temporary solution:

*Have looked a bit at the time format issue. The root cause is probably that Microsoft switched from : to . as clock "separator" in Windows2016 / .NET4 [1]
It explains why this works in the old solution, but not in the new one.*

*Has tried to solve this at OS level, by changing how the time format is set for Norwegian language by building new Locale [2]. Unfortunately this did not solve the problem and the page will still fail if the browser language is set to Norwegian language.*

*But I made a rule on the LB that replaces the "Accept-Language" request header to en_US, and then it works. Do not consider this a complete solution, as all users will be forced into English language, but may be a potential workaround to test further (with English language) until you find a permanent solution.*

[1] https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15175/NET-Internationalization-The-Developer-s-Guide-to

[2] https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnste/2015/08/27/locale-builder-and-finnish-or-other-locales/